# Nested filter returning empty array

Tags: javascript

Below is the data that I am receiving and I am trying to filter so that a new array contains only objects with the desired location.

However, I'm running into an issue where my function is returning `[]`, an empty array.

data:

```
[
  { data: [[Object], [Object], [Object]], id: 1 },
  { data: [[Object]], id: 2 },
  { data: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]], id: 3 }
];
```

data[1]:

```
{"data": [{"name": "Joe", "job": "N/A", "location": "Los Angeles"}], "id": 2}
```

This is my current function:

```
const locations = ["Los Angeles", "Chicago"];
...
const filteredData = data.filter((i) =>
    i.data.filter((j) => locations.includes(j.location)),
);
return filteredData;
```

What is wrong and how can I fix this and get it filtering correctly?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see all that it's doing. I tried your single data example in your code snippet and it appears to function as expected. It certainly doesn't return an empty array. I think the issue is elsewhere, perhaps in that "...".

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code sample, please provide more content to this.

Comment: cant see any problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the callback you pass to the `Array.filter()`, you need to return a `boolean` value to filter the array. If you do not return anything, the filter returns an empty array.

But in your case, you are returning inner filtered array that returns at least an empty array and the outer filter behaves it as a `true` value. So the outer filter will return all of the items in the original array. (not an empty one as you stated)

Also you are returning `filteredData` in a place where it results in a syntax error.

```js
const data = [
    {"data": [{"name": "Joe", "job": "N/A", "location": "Los Angeles"}], "id": 2},
    {"data": [{"name": "Jane", "job": "N/A", "location": "Charlotte"}], "id": 3},
 ]
const locations = ["Los Angeles", "Chicago"];

const filteredData = data.filter((i) =>
    i.data.filter((j) => locations.includes(j.location)).length > 0,
);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: however this is correct, but without the .length > 0 it would return everything because an empty array would result in true statement too.
This probably doesn't explain why he's getting an empty array returned

Comment: @JoostK You're right. I just updated the answer to include this behavior in the second section.

Answer (score 1):

Another Option is use `some()` to get your expected result. This way you don't need to loop through all item in data array comparing to `filter()`

```js
const data = [
  { data: [{ name: "Joe", job: "N/A", location: "Los Angeles" }], id: 2 },
  { data: [{ name: "Jane", job: "N/A", location: "Charlotte" }], id: 3 },
  { data: [{ name: "Sam", job: "N/A", location: "SSS" }], id: 4 },
  {
    data: [
      { name: "John", job: "N/A", location: "AAA" },
      { name: "Doe", job: "N/A", location: "BBB" },
    ],
    id: 5,
  },
];
const locations = ["Los Angeles", "Chicago", "AAA"];

const existData = data.filter(el =>
  el.data.some(item => locations.includes(item.location))
);

console.log(existData);
```

If you also want to filter the data array, you can do like below.

```js
const data = [
  { data: [{ name: "Joe", job: "N/A", location: "Los Angeles" }], id: 2 },
  { data: [{ name: "Jane", job: "N/A", location: "Charlotte" }], id: 3 },
  { data: [{ name: "Sam", job: "N/A", location: "SSS" }], id: 4 },
  {
    data: [
      { name: "John", job: "N/A", location: "AAA" },
      { name: "Doe", job: "N/A", location: "BBB" },
    ],
    id: 5,
  },
];
const locations = ["Los Angeles", "Chicago", "AAA"];

const filteredData = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const filteredItem = cur.data.filter(item => locations.includes(item.location));
  if (filteredItem.length) {
    acc.push({ ...cur, data: filteredItem });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredData);
```